# C#: Inline bulk edit a class, possible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inline, edit, bulk

using C# (Unity), just wondering if it's possible to bulk edit a class inline using something like this:

```
transform.Find("Difficulty/3").GetComponent<Button>()=>{
    this.interactible = true;
    this.color = SStatusEffect;
    this.blahblah = whatever;
}
transform.Find("Difficulty/5").GetComponent<Button>()=>{
    this.interactible = true;
    this.color = SStatusEffect;
    this.blahblah = whatever;
}
```

I know it's possible to do inline functions for events and stuff, but is this sort of thing possible?

Thanks!

Just looking for an alternative to this as it gets tedious in larger/complex scenarios.

```
transform.Find("Difficulty/5").GetComponent<Button>().interactible = true;
transform.Find("Difficulty/5").GetComponent<Button>().color = SStatusEffect;
transform.Find("Difficulty/5").GetComponent<Button>().blahblah = whatever;
```

or this

```
Button but = transform.Find("Difficulty/3").GetComponent<Button>();
but.interactible = true;
but.color = SStatusEffect;
but.blahblah = whatever;
```

Comment: what is the problem on your second approach where you have a variable with the result of `GetComponent`?? IMHO that's the easiest and most concise way.

Comment: The question is if the first option is possible. I find the latter tedious in complex scenarios with dozens of different class types/members all requiring their own different typed vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get something like what you want with an extension method, like so:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void Mutate<T>(this T obj, Action<T> mutations) =>
        mutations(obj);
}
```

And you call it like:

```
transform.Find("Difficulty/5").GetComponent<Button>().Mutate(o => {
    o.interactible = true;
    o.color = SStatusEffect;
    o.blahblah = whatever;
});
```

Though I personally don't find (hehe, get it? find?) that much more readable than the regular if-let pattern:

```
if(transform.Find("Difficulty/5").GetComponent<Button>() is {} button)
{
    button.interactible = true;
    button.color = SStatusEffect;
    button.blahblah = whatever;
}
```

Comment: Hellz yeah that last one is the one! I like how it visually groups all the changes together, making is more readable when this sort of thing is happening multiple times in a row.

Question:
Is the if statement required, or is there an even shorter way to set that up?

Thanks!

Comment: It's required, C# only supports the if-let pattern like C++ (though much, much more feature-packed). VB.NET supports both if-let and `with` -- `with` is exactly what you want, it captures an expression and lets you call property setters on it.

Comment: Performance-wise, the `if` part is equivalent to a `not null` check, which isn't that out of place when working with components anyway. YMMV.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much! Last question, would you mind an example using 'with'? I can't seem to find that online, or is it the same statement?

Comment: Again, `with` is VB.NET, not C#. You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement